# Reset/Clear date variable in workflow loop (using REST API calls)

Tags: workflow, workflow-variable, loop

I use Sharepoint Online and Sharepoint Designer 2013 workflows.
I have a loop workflow that uses variables in date format. When the loop starts again it uses the variable from the first loop.

Normally, when a date field is blank, variable is set as 01/01/0001 and then the value is taken from a date field using REST API and GET call. Then, when the loop runs again and tries to get a date value from second item in the list with blank date, the date remains from the first item in the list.

How can I reset date variables?

[image]

The first time the command: `then get Asbestos from Variable: item (Output to Variable: asbestosDate`) is run, trying to read an empty date field, it returns 01/01/0001 which is what I want.

If the command: `then get Asbestos from Variable: item (Output to Variable: asbestosDate)` is run, trying to read a date from a field WITH date, it returns correct date:

Then, if the same call is run after the previous call WITH date, the same dates remains stored in this variable.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

try to "initialize" the date-variable before the REST-call. When the date is not set, your variable will not be modified - so you'll need to ensure it is always modified using "something".

If you're using a SharePoint 2010 Workflow using SharePoint designer you could use the `Add time to date`-Action like this:
[image]

Comment: please could you be more specific?

Comment: @Maciek: Probably, but what is the question about? SharePoint-Workflows? Created using SharePoint-Designer?

Comment: i added a screenshot and a note below it.

Comment: I updated the answer to include an image from a 2010-Workflow. I have no 2013-Workflow Services at hands right now.

Comment: @Maciek: set `AsbestosDate` to `BlankDate` right after setting `BlankDate` will not work for you?

Comment: weirdly, no :/ I tried it.

Comment: then, I am at a loss. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by adding ELSE BRANCH to the bottom on every IF statement.

Now it's:

```
if..1
if...2
else....3
```